# Appending GET parameters on HREF tag with PHP

Tags: php, href

I'm working on a code like this:

```
<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];
$url_tag = $_POST['url_tag'];
$url_back = 'https://www.page.example.com/page.php?';
$query='id='.$id.'&url_tag='.$url_tag;
$url = $url_back.$query;
echo 'Look how this url shows up: '.$url;
echo '<a href='.$url.'>Click here</a>';
?>
```

This is, the page receives two POST parameters. Then prepare a link to `https://www.page.example.com/page.php?` and I append those two parameters as GET parameters with the ids `id` and `url_tag` respectively.

Then I display how the whole link looks like. It shows up correctly, in this case `https://www.page.example.com/page.php?id=ID&url_tag=URL_TAG`, where ID and URL_TAG are the actual values received as POST parameters.

However, when I click on the '*Click here*' link, it redirects me to `https://www.page.example.com/page.php?`, which is the url without any GET parameter.

Why is that happening and how would I solve it? I've tried to feed HREF with urlencode($url) instead, but it redirects me to an address flooded with undesired characters...

Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace the last line of your code by this:

```
echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Click here</a>';
```

It should work.

Comment: Just as a hint to anyone (especially PHP noobs, as we all were at one time or another) who overlooks the reason this worked, the original would have been missing the double quotes in the generated HTML, so Levon's code shows the correct way to add them in.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/function.http-build-query.php), it takes care of any URL character compatibility issues for you...

```
// assuming you've already checked and validated your $_POST parameters
$query = http_build_query(array(
    'id'      => $_POST['id'],
    'url_tag' => $_POST['url_tag']
));
$url = 'https://www.page.example.com/page.php?' . $query;
?>

<a href="<?= $url ?>">Click here</a>
```

Comment: I've tried your solution as well. But I'm getting this error **"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' "**. That's pointing to the line "$query = http_build_query(["

Comment: @user2957378 Time to upgrade PHP. Short array syntax has been around since 5.4. I'll fix my answer up for you though

Comment: It's not my PC who is complaining, it's my paid remote server :D.